# facebook requests 2.0 sender id

Tags: facebook, api, apprequests

How can I take the sender id from a Request 2.0.
I know it returns an object with the request id and the recipients ids but
I don't how to get the sender's id.

Answer (score 1):

At the time the request is sent you'll know who the sender is because they'll be logged into your app, so you can get it then.

At the time the request is received, you'll be iterating through the requests, and will be able to see the sender of each one. The code for this is listed in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests):

The response for a GET request to check a request's details is:

```
{
  "id": "REQUEST_OBJECT_ID", 
  "application": {
    "name": "APP_DISPLAY_NAME", 
    "canvas_name": "APP_NAME",  // This is identical to the app namespace
    "namespace": "APP_NAMESPACE", 
    "id": "APP_ID"
  }, 
  "from": {
    "name": "SENDER_USER_NAME", 
    "id": "SEND_USER_ID"
  }, 
  "message": "Check out this Awesome Request!", 
  "created_time": "2012-01-24T00:43:22+0000", 
  "type": "apprequest"
}
```

If the 'from' isn't available it may be that the sending user has subsequently blocked your app, disabled their account, etc. If that's the case, you can just delete the request without showing the user who it was from

Comment: It is possible for people to send requests for your app without being a user of your app, in which case you cannot determine the sender.  see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/239476836116522

Comment: Ah, yes, i see that that bug report could affect the OP's usage of the API - but my answer is valid in the general case i think (and will be once the bug is fixed too)

Comment: I think the response object is different after the Requests 2.0 https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/569/
I need to get the user id in facebook application so he won't have loged in. In which Bug are you reffering to ?

Comment: I am also trying to get the user Id from the signed_request object and not able the object has no user_id although I am seen in documentation one https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: The user id is only in the signed_request if the current user has already authorised your app - otherwise it would violate privacy to tell you who the user is

Comment: Thanks so he has to authorize the application to get his id through a facebook dialog ?

Comment: Yes, you can't tell who a user is unless they've authorised your app